# Uncoupled Linear System: Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to make sense of a problem I was given in class and I want to know if I am on the right track. The question is as follows:

> If $\vec{u}(t)$ and $\vec{v}(t)$ are solutions of the linear system ($ \vec{x}^{'}=A\vec{x}$), prove that for any constants $b$ and $c$, $\vec{w}(t)=b\vec{u}(t)+c\vec{v}(t)$ is a solution.

If I understand correctly. I want to show that $ \vec{w}^{'}=A\vec{w}$. Since we are given that $\vec{u}(t)$ and $\vec{v}(t)$ are solutions of the linear system, then it follows that $ \vec{u}^{'}=A\vec{u}$ and $ \vec{v}^{'}=A\vec{v}$. Thus:

\begin{align}
    \vec{u}' &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{1j} u_{j} \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{2j} u_{j} \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{nj} u_{j}
         \end{bmatrix} &
    \vec{v}' &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{1j} v_{j} \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{2j} v_{j} \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{nj} v_{j}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

We define $\vec{w}(t)=b\vec{u}(t)+c\vec{v}(t)$. After taking the derivative, we get:

\begin{align}
    \vec{w}' &= b\begin{bmatrix}
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{1j} u_{j} \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{2j} u_{j} \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{nj} u_{j}
         \end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{1j} v_{j} \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{2j} v_{j} \\
           \vdots \\
           \sum_{1=j}^{n}a_{nj} v_{j}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

Thus to finish proving $\vec{w}$ is a solution of the linear system, I have to verify what I have above ($\vec{w}$') equals to $A\vec{w}$. Am I on the right track?

There was a second part to the question that defined the matrix to be 
\begin{align}
    \vec{A} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 &0\\
           0 &-2
         \end{bmatrix} 
  \end{align} 
It was then asked of us to find $\vec{u}(t)$ and $\vec{v}(t)$ of the linear system such that every solution is a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. My solution to that linear system was:

\begin{align}
    \vec{x} &= c_{1}\vec{u}+
c_{2}\vec{v}
  \end{align} 
Where:
\begin{align}
    \vec{u} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           e^t\\
           0
         \end{bmatrix} &
\vec{v} & =\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           e^{-2t}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

---

Sorry for the long read, but thank you so much for taking the time to read this. I appreciate any feedback you may give in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ in components. Use the fact $\vec{u}'=A\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}'=A\vec{v}$. Since 
$$\vec{w}=b\vec{u}+c\vec{u}$$
Then 
$$\vec{w}'=b\vec{u}'+c\vec{v}'$$
What can you get using the facts you have?

For the second part, you had a typo in either the matrix or the solution with $2$ or $-2$.